Thriller book with a climactic scene where the protagonist knows that weapons are being smuggled in the coffins of deceased veterans/POWs
This popped into mind for some reason during Veteran's Day services. The part that has stuck with me was a scene near the end of the book, but I think it featured a military investigator who encountered a scheme to smuggle munitions onto the black market by flying them onto US soil hidden in the coffins of either veterans recently killed, or POW remains being returned. If the former, it would like have been the Middle East or Afghanistan conflicts. If the latter, likely Vietnam or Korea. The scene that has stuck out in my mind was that the investigator had received proof of the plane that was carrying the munitions, and had burned several favors to get government backup to stop the plane and have it searched. I remember that the first cursory search turned up nothing, resulting in the protagonist having to order one or more of the coffins to be opened and the body temporarily removed, which they noted was career suicide if they were wrong, but indeed, they found RPG components in a compartment under the body of at least one of the coffins opened. I think that the bodies were being flown back by a military contractor, not by the government themselves.
I want to say that the investigator was female, but that's not terribly firm in my head. I think that this was a part of a series. I would have read it somewhere in the last two decades (I know... that doesn't narrow it down terribly), probably between 5-15 years ago since that was when I did a lot of my reading of military mystery (I think I started with the Jack Reacher books, and kept branching out as I found new authors). It would likely have been a standard size paperback, 200-300 pages, in English, checked out from the library.

There's a TVTropes page for this. https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CoffinContraband  Any sound familiar? Possibly Tom Clancy's book Without Remorse, although that was drug smuggling, not weapons.

@Pete: That's a good call, but unfortunately, none of them sound familiar. I've read two of the books on their ("Two for the Money" and I think "Without Remorse"), but I'm certain it was related to military remains, and that it was weapons.
